# Verb for action; "Actioning"

Tags: grammar, verbs, orthography

I am currently writing an email to office management.

I am asking for office management to action a fix. I want to ask them in a polite manner.

The sentence I have: "Please consider actioning a fix."

"actioning" is highlighted. I want to use professionally articulated grammar and spelling.

a) How would I ask them to politely consider helping me out?

b) Why does "action" not come in the form of a verb?

Comment: (b) because _action_ is a noun already derived from a verb _act_. That's not the verb you want to use here, though.

Comment: Initially I didn't make use of the word "consider", and had "Please action a fix". However, since I'm not in charge of office management, I cannot command them to action a fix. Even if I do so politely by starting off the sentence with "Please". I stated my issue, and am asking them to do something, as I don't just want them to confirm and forget. I want them to be aware that I expect some sort of action to be performed in order for my issue to be considered resolved.

Comment: If just asking them politely to fix it is too simple, I guess you could use "Please expedite the necessary maintenance procedures as soon as possible"

Comment: What's wrong with "Please consider fixing this."?

Comment: @TrevorD Office management isn't responsible for fixing the issue. James Random's comment perfectly puts into words what I couldn't. Office management would "expedite" to the necessary department/team.

Comment: In that case, personally I would say "Please arrange for this to be fixed a.s.a.p.."  Why do you need 'posh words' like "expedite the necessary maintenance procedures"?

Comment: I hasten to add that my suggestion was intended as a joke! @TrevorD 's wording is far more sensible.

Comment: Or just *Please have this fixed.* Even if they don't fix it themselves, they can *get* it fixed.

Comment: What is your would-be "actioning a fix" supposed to mean in plain English? As it stands, it sounds like some sort of annoying jargon, some bureaucratic "in-speak" that risks a reprimand or a bingo.

Comment: What about "Please consider **implementing** a fix"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) "Can you please fix this?"

B) There are verbs related to *action*.  As John Lawler says, the root of *action* is the verb *act*. But *act* is intransitive, so it can't be used in this kind of phrase - you cannot *act a fix*.

Another verb related to *act*, *enact*, is transitive, and its meaning more-or-less fits this context:

> **enact**
>
> 2 Put into practice (an idea or suggestion)
>   *‘the pressure group's aim was to see the proposals enacted’*
>
> https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enact

It is grammtically correct to say, "enact a fix," but it's not idiomatic. Perhaps because *fix* is already a verb.

Comment: I like that. I could phrase it as follow: "Please consider enacting a fix.". James Random commented on the Question, in reply to one of my comments. He worded it  perfectly, bar the asap. I would leave off the asap, as this conveys an urgency that I can't justify.

Comment: A) "Can you please fix this?" is probably the most sensible to use. I also should have kept it simple, rather than over-complicate.

Answer (score 2):

"Act" is a verb; its noun is "action". You cannot use a noun in place of a verb. If you mean fixing something, politely and professionally, you can say:

--I was wondering if you could kindly fix this/this issue.

--Is it possible for you to kindly fix this/this issue?

--Could you kindly fix this issue (as I am not able to do so)?

The sentence "please consider actioning a fix" is by no means grammatical or even professional.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can use a noun as a verb. English does it all the time. Although some people consider that verbing weirds language.

Comment: How can a 'fix' be 'kind' or 'kindly'?

Comment: @Trevor "kindly" is a [sentence adverb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sentence_adverb)

Comment: @Acccumulation I've never heard of one of them!  To my British ears, all those suggestions sound horrible!